# Redirect to an absolute url(folder in my project) in view of MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a link in my view model in MVC4.the link should refer to a folder in my root direction .

I google it ,but all of them was about **redirect to absolute url in controller not view**

As you can see i need something like this :

```
     <li>@Html.RouteLink("fileManager", "~/fileman")</li>
```

The fileman folder is out of view folder ,i just want to create a link to **mypcname:33978/fileman/index.html** address

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Url.Content`

example:

```
<a href="@(Url.Content("~/fileman"))">YOUR TEXT HERE</a>
```

Comment: You would need to use single quotes for this to work `href='@(Url.Content("..."))'>`

Comment: Thank you mohammad ,my question has a low rate ,but thank you for answering

Comment: Also, the parenthesis `@(..)` is unnecessary, just call `@Url.Content`

Comment: @James: thank you for the feedback, I was suggesting the solution more like a Pseudo-code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to resolve a relative path to an absolute path

```
@Html.RouteLink("fileManager", Server.MapPath("~/fileman"))
```

Comment: i did that but i got this error : A route named 'E:\Projects migration to Qazvin\EducationModel\EducationMVC\fileman\index.html' could not be found in the route collection.i am sure that i have this file in this direction

Comment: @EA do you have got any web config file in that directory?

Comment: How about just using `<a href='@Server.MapPath("~/fileman")'>some text</a>`?

Comment: @EA Well that's because you are trying to resolve a *file* as a *route* - routes don't physically exist on disk they are determined using routing rules. If you simply want to provide a link to a *physical* directory then you shouldn't use `RouteLink` at all. It's unclear as to what exactly it is you are trying to do, I provided an answer based on your requirement to resolve a relative path to an absolute one.